# Spring MVC - is the insert statement written correctly?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am trying to insert a record into the database i am using Spring 3.0. I am not using Hibernate or any persistence framework. Would like to know if the DAO was correctly written or whats different ways it can be written:

**OfficersDAO**

```
public void saveOfficer(Officers officer) {
        logger.info("In saveOfficer");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        try{

            logger.info("Values are "+officer.getUserName()+" "+officer.getPassword()+" "+officer.getfName()+" "+officer.getoName()+" "+officer.getDivisionNo()+" "+officer.getPositionId()+" "+officer.getEmailAdd()+" "+dateFormat.format(officer.getStartDate())+" "+dateFormat.format(officer.getEndDate())+" "+ officer.getGenderId()+" "+officer.getPhoneNo()+" "+dateFormat.format(officer.getDob()));


            String sql= "INSERT INTO crimetrack.tblofficers (userName,password, fName, lName, oName, " +
                        "divisionNo, poisitionId, emailAdd, startDate, endDate, genderId, " +
                        "phoneNo, dob) VALUES (:userName,:password, :fName, :lName, :oName, :divisionNo, "+
                        ":poisitionId, :emailAdd, :startDate, :endDate, :genderId, " +
                        ":phoneNo, :dob)";



            logger.debug("Executing saveOfficer String " + sql);
            int count = getJdbcTemplate().update(sql,new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("userName",officer.getUserName())
                    .addValue("password", officer.getPassword())
                    .addValue("fName", officer.getfName())
                    .addValue("lName", officer.getlName())
                    .addValue("oName", officer.getoName())
                    .addValue("divisionNo", officer.getDivisionNo())
                    .addValue("positionId",officer.getPositionId())
                    .addValue("emailAdd", officer.getEmailAdd())
                    .addValue("startDate", dateFormat.format(officer.getStartDate()))
                    .addValue("endDate", dateFormat.format(officer.getEndDate()))
                    .addValue("genderId", officer.getGenderId())
                    .addValue("phoneNo",officer.getPhoneNo())
                    .addValue("dob", dateFormat.format(officer.getDob())));

            System.out.println(sql);
            logger.info(count +" Rows affected in tblOfficers");



        }catch(Exception e){

            logger.error("Could not save officer ", e);
        }


    }


public static class OfficerMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<Officers>{

         public Officers mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

                Officers officer = new Officers();
                officer.setUserName(rs.getString("userName"));
                officer.setDivisionNo(rs.getInt("divisionNo"));
                officer.setDob(rs.getDate("dob"));
                officer.setEmailAdd(rs.getString("emailAdd"));
                officer.setEndDate(rs.getDate("endDate"));
                officer.setfName(rs.getString("fName"));
                officer.setGenderId(rs.getString("genderId"));
                officer.setlName(rs.getString("lName"));
                officer.setoName(rs.getString("oName"));
                officer.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                officer.setPhoneNo(rs.getString("phoneNo"));
                officer.setPositionId(rs.getInt("positionId"));
                officer.setStartDate(rs.getDate("startDate"));
                return officer;
            }       
    }
```

Comment: You have a typo in your `sql` string - check how you've spelt `positionId`. Copy/paste and repetition errors like that are one of the reasons why DAOs generally don't get written like this any more.

Comment: Spelling was fixed but the same problem persist

Comment: OK so the insert doesn't work *at all*? Does it throw an exception or are you just seeing "0 rows affected" ?

Comment: @millhouse it just throws an exception i am getting the "Could not save officer"

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @millhouse i got thru with this error thanks for your concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-wrote the code and this worked for me :

```
public void saveOfficer(Officers officer) {
        logger.info("In saveOfficer");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");


        try{

            logger.info("Values are "+officer.getUserName()+" "+StringSecurity.EncryptString(officer.getPassword())+" "+officer.getfName()+" "+officer.getoName()+" "+officer.getDivisionNo()+" "+officer.getPositionId()+" "+officer.getEmailAdd()+" "+dateFormat.format(officer.getStartDate())+" "+dateFormat.format(officer.getEndDate())+" "+ officer.getGenderId()+" "+officer.getPhoneNo()+" "+dateFormat.format(officer.getDob()));

            int count = getJdbcTemplate().update("INSERT INTO crimetrack.tblofficers (userName,password, fName, lName, oName, divisionNo, positionId, emailAdd, startDate, endDate, genderId,phoneNo, dob,badgeNo) "+
                                                "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
                                                , new Object[]{officer.getUserName(),StringSecurity.EncryptString(officer.getPassword()),officer.getfName(),
                                                 officer.getlName(),officer.getoName(),officer.getDivisionNo(),officer.getPositionId(),
                                                 officer.getEmailAdd(),officer.getStartDate(),officer.getEndDate(),officer.getGenderId(),
                                                 officer.getPhoneNo(),officer.getDob(),officer.getBadgeNo()});

        logger.info(count +" Rows affected in tblOfficers");



        }catch(Exception e){

            logger.error("Could not save officer ", e);
        }       
    }
```